# What does the ?P stand for in this regex?

Tags: regex

I am having problems understanding the following regex:

```
regexp="(?P<date>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})\S+\s(?P<proto>\w+)\S+\s(?P<sid>\S)\s+(? P<sip>\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})(\s+(?P<sport>\d+))?\s+(?P<dip>\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})(:)?\s(?P<dport>\d+)((:)?\s+(?P<info>\S+\s\S+)\s+\[(?P<comment>.*)\])?"
```

0 or 1
date={normalize_date($date)}
plugin_sid={translate($sid)}
src_ip={$sip}
src_port={$sport}
dst_ip={$dip}
dst_port={$dport}
protocol={$proto}
userdata1={$info}
userdata2={$comment}
What does the ?P stand for? Could someone help me make sense of this monster by spelling out the logic?

Comment: Any context could help...

Comment: It is a regular expression to match logs generated by a low interaction honeypot named honeyd.
This regular expression matches strings like te following:
2013-09-25-01:05:15.1082 icmp(1) - 192.168.X.X 192.168.X.X: 8(0): 84
OR
2013-09-25-01:07:14.7951 tcp(6) - 192.168.X.X 55394 192.168.X.X 20: 52 S [Linux 2.4 ts]

Comment: Most packets have date protocol sourceip:sourceport destip:destport connection_state

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(?P...)` is a [named group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html).

Oh, and `(? P<sip>` might be invalid (I don't think a space is allowed there).

If you have any other questions, **[this](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl)** is a useful resource for explaining regex, although it doesn't work for `(?P...)`.

Explanation of your regex without the named groups (so just replace "group and capture to \1" with "group and capture to 'date'" for the first one, and so on) ([link](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=%28%5Cd%7B4%7D-%5Cd%7B2%7D-%5Cd%7B2%7D-%5Cd%7B2%7D%3A%5Cd%7B2%7D%3A%5Cd%7B2%7D%29%5CS%2B%5Cs%28%5Cw%2B%29%5CS%2B%5Cs%28%5CS%29%5Cs%2B%28%5Cd%7B1%2C3%7D%5C.%5Cd%7B1%2C3%7D%5C.%5Cd%7B1%2C3%7D%5C.%5Cd%7B1%2C3%7D%29%28%5Cs%2B%28%5Cd%2B%29%29%3F%5Cs%2B%28%5Cd%7B1%2C3%7D%5C.%5Cd%7B1%2C3%7D%5C.%5Cd%7B1%2C3%7D%5C.%5Cd%7B1%2C3%7D%29%28%3A%29%3F%5Cs%28%5Cd%2B%29%28%28%3A%29%3F%5Cs%2B%28%5CS%2B%5Cs%5CS%2B%29%5Cs%2B%5C%5B%28.%2a%29%5C%5D%29%3F)):

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d{4}                    digits (0-9) (4 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -                        '-'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d{2}                    digits (0-9) (2 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -                        '-'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d{2}                    digits (0-9) (2 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -                        '-'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d{2}                    digits (0-9) (2 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    :                        ':'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d{2}                    digits (0-9) (2 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    :                        ':'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d{2}                    digits (0-9) (2 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \S+                      non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f,
                           and " ") (1 or more times (matching the
                           most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \2:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \w+                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (1 or
                             more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \2
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \S+                      non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f,
                           and " ") (1 or more times (matching the
                           most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \3:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \S                       non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f,
                             and " ")
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \3
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \4:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d{1,3}                  digits (0-9) (between 1 and 3 times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d{1,3}                  digits (0-9) (between 1 and 3 times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d{1,3}                  digits (0-9) (between 1 and 3 times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d{1,3}                  digits (0-9) (between 1 and 3 times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \4
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \5 (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \6:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times
                               (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \6
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of \5 (NOTE: because you are using a
                           quantifier on this capture, only the LAST
                           repetition of the captured pattern will be
                           stored in \5)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \7:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d{1,3}                  digits (0-9) (between 1 and 3 times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d{1,3}                  digits (0-9) (between 1 and 3 times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d{1,3}                  digits (0-9) (between 1 and 3 times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d{1,3}                  digits (0-9) (between 1 and 3 times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \7
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \8 (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    :                        ':'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of \8 (NOTE: because you are using a
                           quantifier on this capture, only the LAST
                           repetition of the captured pattern will be
                           stored in \8)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \9:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \9
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (                        group and capture to \10 (optional
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \11 (optional
                             (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      :                        ':'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )?                       end of \11 (NOTE: because you are using
                             a quantifier on this capture, only the
                             LAST repetition of the captured pattern
                             will be stored in \11)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \12:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \S+                      non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t,
                               \f, and " ") (1 or more times
                               (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \s                       whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ")
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \S+                      non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t,
                               \f, and " ") (1 or more times
                               (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \12
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \[                       '['
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (                        group and capture to \13:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      .*                       any character except \n (0 or more
                               times (matching the most amount
                               possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \13
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \]                       ']'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )?                       end of \10 (NOTE: because you are using a
                           quantifier on this capture, only the LAST
                           repetition of the captured pattern will be
                           stored in \10)
```